# trying to change content on a page based on click

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

im trying to change the photo content of a page. at the top of the page i have a horizontal photo strip, which uses GET to find PHOTOTYPE so the website knows which photo strip to load. all of the photos on the lower page are related to which photo in the strip is selected. i want to be able to change the lower content of the page based on which photo in the upper strip is clicked.

here is some code i have so far

```
    <?php
include_once("resources/init.php");
include_once("db_conx.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id= '$idd'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $description = $row["description"];
        $filename = $row["filename"];
        $thumb1 = $row["thumb1"];
        $thumb2 = $row["thumb2"];
        $thumb3 = $row["thumb3"];
        $desc1 = $row["desc1"];
        $desc2 = $row["desc2"];
        $desc3 = $row["desc3"];
}
?>
```

$idd is supposed to change based on which image in the strip is clicked, to display all related photos below, i cant get it to work, how can i change the $idd to the $id of the clicked image without reloading the page?

```
    function menuclick(){
    $idd = "<?php echo $id ?>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $('#iid').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4bm2m6fj/)

This is the *javascript* version:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        iid.value = this.id;
    });
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4bm2m6fj/1/)

Comment: i dont know how to use jquery, is there a javascript solution?

Comment: @peter Yes there is. I updated the answer with the javascript version as well and a link to a demo of the code :)

Comment: on submit, does the page need to reload to change the photos in the lower section? can i make the strip photos themselves act as the submit buttons while at the same time changing $iid?

Comment: Are you trying to display the pictures in a bigger size when clicked below the smaller one? If so, then you don't really have to submit them. Can you please give more details on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yes, small photo strip at the top and below that a large display of photos. when image in small film strip is clicked the numerous images below the small film strip all change to match what was clicked in small film strip

Comment: so far, no solution for this function im trying to make

Comment: @peter "numerous images"? There are a lot of other images? Can you provide a simple JSFiddle of your html structure?

Comment: the lower part of the page has many images AND VIDEOS. all are stored in my database. sql and php echo the images and videos that are unique to the image selected in the top image strip. when the image in the image strip is selected by clicking on it, the entire lower page displays info from the database based on the upper images $id, which then will only display info which is associated with that unique $id, thats how the page gets its content.

Comment: @peter You will have to use ajax for the dynamic content generation. Once your PHP receives the _id_, it should generate the new content's html codes and echo it back to the requesting page. You ajax code should set the received codes to the page, replacing the old content with the new one.